# How to overcome "iif" limitations with subqueries?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables (`A` and `B`). I want to implement such logic to table `B`:

```
[Bank] AS (iif( Some_Statement,
                (SELECT [Money] FROM [ATM] WHERE [B].[Currency] = [A].[Currency] ),
                [NoMoney]
               )
          )
```

I get an error: `Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.`

Is there a way to implement such logic on creation of the tables? It doesn't look hard.

Comment: Don't use IIF to begin with. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a column that has to be autofilled with a correct value based on a value in another table. Between tables there is connection. Table B stores FK and table A PK.

Comment: In any case this isn't a limitation of IIF, the statement doesn't make sense. Is this part of a CTE? Why use `IIF` in a CTE?

Comment: If you want to combine values from tables use a JOIN. The expression just doesn't make sense.

Comment: There are no A and B tables in this snippet. `AS` in queries is used to define aliases *or* CTEs, which means that `Bank` is a CTE. The error itself is crystal-clear: IIF is meant to pick one of two values. Using a query that returns multiple values in there is simply an error. CASE wouldn't work either

Comment: It's not combining values it decides which value this column should get. It will get either value from the same table [NoMoney] or value from different table [A].[Money]

Comment: `Bank` is a column and `AS` is used to define a default value. I had this working but decided that `Money` should be in another table. Before it looked like this: `[Bank] AS (iif( Some_Statement, [Money], [NoMoney]))`

Comment: @Pomme you describe what you think the solution looks like, not what the problem is. *Tables* go in the `FROM` clause. To combine tables use an INNER JOIN. You won't have to change the `IIF` statement at all, eg `select IIF(A.Field=3,A.Money,B.NoMoney) from A inner join B on A.Currency=B.Currency`

Comment: The thing is I need that select clause `as` a default value for column `Bank` I will get  back to this later, thanks for advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the discussion in comments I get the feeling, that this was going the wrong direction. Might be because of your very direct question about `IIF()`...

If I get this correctly you try to add a *computed column* to you table. Something along this:

```
DECLARE @tblTest TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY
                       ,SomeValue VARCHAR(100)
                       ,[Test] AS IIF(SomeValue IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(SomeValue,'Blah'), 'Default if null'));

INSERT INTO @tblTest(SomeValue) VALUES('Test');
INSERT INTO @tblTest(SomeValue) VALUES(NULL);

SELECT * FROM @tblTest;
```

The result

```
ID  SomeValue   Test
1   Test        TestBlah
2   NULL        Default if null
```

Now you want to get the value for the computed column not just from some simple scalar computation, but you want to pick it from a table.

Here I will try to simulate your issue. Next time it is up to you to do this yourself. Providing DDL, sample data and the expected output together with your own attempts is the best chance to get the answer you are waiting for.

This is the table `B` from where you want to get the value.
Later we will ask for `'Test'` and not for `'xyz'`.

```
CREATE TABLE tblB (ID INT IDENTITY
                  ,SomeResultColumn VARCHAR(100)
                  ,SomeConditionColumn VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO tblB(SomeResultColumn,SomeConditionColumn) VALUES('not wanted','xyz')
                                                            ,('wanted','Test');
GO
```

--This is what you are trying to do, but I out-commented it because of the error you've got.
--A *computed column* does not allow for a `SELECT`. This is not bound to the `IIF()`

```
--CREATE  TABLE tblA (ID INT IDENTITY
--                   ,SomeValue VARCHAR(100)
--                   ,[Test] AS IIF(SomeValue IS NOT NULL,(SELECT b.SomeResultColumn FROM tblB b WHERE b.SomeConditionColumn=SomeValue),'Default if null'));
--GO
```

--But what we can do - and the error message is telling so - provide a scalar expression:
--A Scalar Function is exactly this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetMyComputedColumn(@Condition VARCHAR(100)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(100) AS 
BEGIN 
    RETURN (SELECT b.SomeResultColumn --You might use `TOP 1` to ensure a scalar result
            FROM tblB b 
            WHERE b.SomeConditionColumn=@Condition); 
END
GO
```

--We can use this function in the `IIF()`:

```
CREATE  TABLE tblA (ID INT IDENTITY
                   ,SomeValue VARCHAR(100)
                   ,[Test] AS IIF(SomeValue IS NOT NULL,dbo.GetMyComputedColumn(SomeValue),'Default if null'));
GO

INSERT INTO tblA(SomeValue) VALUES('Test');
INSERT INTO tblA(SomeValue) VALUES(NULL);

SELECT * FROM tblA;
```

The result

```
ID  SomeValue   Test
1   Test        wanted
2   NULL        Default if null
```

## Should you do this?

The question, if this is a good idea, is something completely different.

Besides the fact, that scalar functions are known as bad performers, the main question is: WHY?

Do you need a persistant default value? In this case a trigger will be a better choice... Or you can use an insert statement with the computed value directly. I'm afraid you are mixing the concepts of *computed columns* and a *default constraint*. The *computed column* cannot be changed...

If you want to compute this value whenever you fetch data from this table, it was much better to use a VIEW or an iTVF, where you simply join the needed value to your result set.

Comment: Thank you for your solution and after reading your "Why" section I decided to drop this column and for it to be resolved in another tool. Many thanks.

Comment: @Pomme This sounds like the best decision :-) Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

If what you are saying is that you want a value from table "B" IF it matches on a value from your main table "A" and if there is no matching value in "B", use a literal as a default, try this:

select
  Bank,
  coalesce( (SELECT Money FROM ATM WHERE Currency = A.Currency), 'NoMoney' ) as 'Type'
from
  ATM A
where
  ....

If the select of [Money] returns null, the literal 'NoMoney' will be used.

If need be, you can have a select on both sides of the coalesce, the right need not be a literal.

Comment: The usage of `[Bank] AS ...` points to a computed column. In a comment the OP tells us *I need that select clause as a default value for column Bank*. I think the whole question is misleading...